# Hbase as sink for Mapreduce: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

```
$ hadoop jar target/projeto5-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fatjar.jar br.edu.ufam.anibrata.HBaseWordCount -input shakespeare.txt -output wcount -numReducers 1
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0x6022bb5c connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=localhost:2181
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-cdh5.11.1--1, built on 06/01/2017 17:37 GMT
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=quickstart.cloudera
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_67
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/avro.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.10.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aws-java-sdk-sts-1.10.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/logredactor-1.0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hue-plugins-3.9.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.10.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/zookeeper.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hadoop-bundle.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-format-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-avro.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-pig.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-nfs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-pig-bundle.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-column.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-aws-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-format-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-nfs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-protobuf.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-azure-datalake-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-scrooge_2.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-generator.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-test-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-scala_2.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-jackson.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-encoding.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-format.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-cascading.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hadoop.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-azure-datalake.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-thrift.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-nfs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/spark-1.6.0-cdh5.11.1-yarn-shuffle.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jline-2.11.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/spark-yarn-shuffle.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/zookeeper.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-registry-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-registry.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-client-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-client.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/avro.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jackson-core-2.2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-distcp.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-datajoin.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-datajoin-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-azure-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-gridmix-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//avro.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-rumen-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//okio-1.4.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-distcp-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//junit-4.11.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-auth-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-archive-logs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-azure.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-extras.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-openstack.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-sls-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-archives.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-nativetask-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-extras-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-rumen.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-nativetask.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-app.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-archives-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-sls.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-gridmix.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//okhttp-2.4.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-auth.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk-0.6.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-streaming.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-ant.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//zookeeper.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-archive-logs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-openstack-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-ant-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.jar
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-696.3.2.el6.x86_64
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=cloudera
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/cloudera
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/cloudera/topicosBD-pis/topicosBD-pis/projeto5
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x6022bb5c0x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:52300, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
17/07/15 20:23:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x15d42b07712000e, negotiated timeout = 40000
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
Sat Jul 15 20:24:23 PDT 2017, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=69886: row 'wcount,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=quickstart.cloudera,60020,1500062548162, seqNum=0

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.throwEnrichedException(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:320)
    at br.edu.ufam.anibrata.HBaseWordCount.run(HBaseWordCount.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at br.edu.ufam.anibrata.HBaseWordCount.main(HBaseWordCount.java:224)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=69886: row 'wcount,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=quickstart.cloudera,60020,1500062548162, seqNum=0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:881)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:31889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
    ... 4 more
```

I am trying to run the wordCount program in MapReduce with HBase as the sink. Now I haven't made any configuration changes in hbase, and I am using the same 'AS IS' provided in the distribution of Cloudera for virtualBox VM. I am not aware of the configuration files for hbase and how to map those to mapreduce and HDFS. Any help or assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a sign that your hbase client is trying to initiate unsecure RPCs while HBase is expecting Kerberos authentication.

Moreover the timeout period should not be short as the minimum number of cells that must be scanned before a timeout check occurs.

The default value is 10000. A smaller value causes timeout checks to occur more often. From your post I can say timeout has happened.

Edit hbase-site.xml and add the following properties, modifying the values as needed.

```
<property>
   <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
   <value>60000</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period</name>
   <value>60000</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.cells.scanned.per.heartbeat.check</name>
   <value>10000</value>
</property>
```

Copy the hbase-site.xml to all your cluster hosts and restart the HBase master and RegionServer processes for the change to take effect.